# Animations on pictures

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

I'm trying to animate the movement of an object.
What I have:

1. A map on which there are certain objects.
2. A picture (let it be a car) that moves across the map at speed.
   What is needed:
   When the user clicks on the map, the code checks whether this color is prohibited in the list (because the car cannot drive through buildings) - it goes to the point the user clicked on and during movement it is always checked whether the next 2 pixels of the picture are the prohibited ones in the color that is in the list, if it is true, it stops, if not, it goes on. Here is my code that should work:

```java
map.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    // Get the touched position on the map
                    float clickedX = event.getX();
                    float clickedY = event.getY();

                    // Get the current position of the car
                    float carX = point.getX();
                    float carY = point.getY();

                    // Check if the clicked pixel is red
                    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) map.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    int clickedPixel = bitmap.getPixel((int) clickedX, (int) clickedY);
                    int pixelColor = getPixelColor((int) clickedX, (int) clickedY);
                    int[] forbiddenColors = {Color.rgb(102,112,127), Color.rgb(76, 76, 76)}; // add any other forbidden colors

                    // If the touched pixel color is a forbidden color, move the car to the nearest possible point that is not forbidden
                    if (isForbiddenColor(pixelColor, forbiddenColors)) {
                        PointF nearestPoint = findNextNonForbiddenPoint(carX, carY, clickedX, clickedY, forbiddenColors, screenWidth, screenHeight);
                        clickedX = nearestPoint.x;
                        clickedY = nearestPoint.y;
                    }

                    // Calculate the distance between the car and the touched point
                    float distance = calculateDistance(carX, carY, clickedX, clickedY);

                    // Calculate the duration it will take to travel the distance at 50 pixels per second
                    long duration = (long) (distance / 50 * 1000);

                    // Create a ValueAnimator to move the car to the touched point
                    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f);
                    animator.setDuration(duration);

                    final float startX = carX;
                    final float startY = carY;
                    final float endX = clickedX;
                    final float endY = clickedY;

                    // Set an UpdateListener to update the carImageView's position during the animation
                    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                            float fraction = animation.getAnimatedFraction();
                            float x = startX + fraction * (endX - startX);
                            float y = startY + fraction * (endY - startY);
                            point.setX(x);
                            point.setY(y);
                        }
                    });

                    // Start the animation
                    animator.start();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

and here some mothods:

```java
// Helper method to check if a color is one of the forbidden colors
    private boolean isForbiddenColor(int color, int[] forbiddenColors) {
        for (int c : forbiddenColors) {
            if (color == c) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private int getPixelColor(int x, int y) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) map.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        return bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
    }

    // Calculate the distance between two points using the Pythagorean theorem
    private float calculateDistance(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
        float dx = x2 - x1;
        float dy = y2 - y1;
        return (float) Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }

    private PointF findNextNonForbiddenPoint(float startX, float startY, float endX, float endY, int[] forbiddenColors, int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {
        // Calculate direction vector from start point to end point
        PointF direction = new PointF(endX - startX, endY - startY);
        // Normalize direction vector
        float distance = (float) Math.sqrt(direction.x * direction.x + direction.y * direction.y);
        if (distance > 0) {
            direction.set(direction.x / distance, direction.y / distance);
        }

        // Check for forbidden colors in 1-pixel steps along the direction vector
        PointF nextPoint = new PointF(startX, startY);
        while (isForbiddenColor(getPixelColor((int) nextPoint.x, (int) nextPoint.y), forbiddenColors)) {
            nextPoint.offset(direction.x, direction.y);
            // If next point is out of bounds, return null
            if (nextPoint.x < 0 || nextPoint.x >= screenWidth || nextPoint.y < 0 || nextPoint.y >= screenHeight) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return nextPoint;
    }
```

Comment: The only suggestion I would make is to use a more descriptive name for the point variable that holds the position of the car. Perhaps carImageView or carPosition would be more appropriate. This would make the code easier to read and understand.

Comment: @sachinthahewawasam, by the way, this code generated ChatGPT, because I didn't find any answers for my questions.